# Android: Synchronize Methods on calling Remote Messenger Service

Tags: android, handler, synchronous, messenger

I want to write a module that connects to a remote Service.

The module can be used by developers in their apps to connect to a specific (bluetooth-)hardware. It should then connect to a single remoteservice that can be updated seperately in the market.

Because the Remote Service is only allowed to have a single thread for all the apps using it at the same time (Only one connection over bluetooth), I have chosen the messenger approach over AIDL.

My problem is now that I wanted to provide a synchronous method in my public API but the service returns in an handler - and as far as I have understood, the handler will allways wait for the current task to finish... So is there any way to get the answer in a differen thread?

the code of the synchronous method as I would like it to be:

```
responseDataSync = new Sync<ResponseData>();

    // Send message
    Message msg = Message.obtain(null, Constants.DATA, 1, 0);

    send(msg);

    try {
        ResponseData responseData = responseDataSync.get();

        // with responseDataSync using a countdown latch to synchronize...
// but it never fires thanks to the handler.
//etc...
```

Thanks in advance. I hope my question was somewhat understandable... ;)

/EDIT: 
I want some method that returns data from the server. like

```
 public ResponseData returnResponse(Data dataToSend)
```

but I can't wait for the service's return because then I am stuck in the thread what blocks the handler from returning...

Comment: you have a (remote) service that you distribute via your apk, and a public api that has to be included in other apps which want to use the service?

Comment: You got me. ;) The library has additional features and should make access to the service as simple as possible - hence the need for a synchronized method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `Handler` is associated with a single message queue. If you send a `Message` from any Thread it will get enqueued there.

The Thread that receives all the Messages will get the appropriate message off the queue and handle it - one by one.

Meaning for you that if you have a Handler and you run all Messages through you handler you don't need synchronization since everything is handled in a single thread.

Edit: to create a Handler that handles messages in a background thread:

```
HandlerThread ht = new HandlerThread("threadName");
ht.start();
Looper looper = ht.getLooper();
Handler.Callback callback = new Handler.Callback() {

    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
        // handled messages are handled in background thread 
        return true;
    }
};
Handler handler = new Handler(looper, callback);

handler.sendEmptyMessage(1337);
```

Edit2: wait on Messages might work like this

```
// available for all threads somehow
final Object waitOnMe = new Object();

HandlerThread ht = new HandlerThread("threadName");
ht.start();
Looper looper = ht.getLooper();
Handler.Callback callback = new Handler.Callback() {

    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
        // handled messages are handled in background thread
        // then notify about finished message.
        synchronized (waitOnMe) {
            waitOnMe.notifyAll();
        }
        return true;
    }
};
Handler handler = new Handler(looper, callback);

// in a different Thread:
synchronized (waitOnMe) {
    handler.sendEmptyMessage(1337);
    try {
        waitOnMe.wait();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // we should have gotten our answer now.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I understood that. That is my problem however. I wanted to have a synchronous method, for example
    public SomeValue returnSomeValue(SomeParameter someParameter)
but I cannot wait for the result from the service because my handler won't return anything as long as I am stuck in executing the method...

Comment: Ok I see. That is a bit more complicated then: basically you would need to put a mechanism that first sends a Message to your Service and then waits for the message you recieve from the service inside `returnSomeValue()`. Another possibility is a regular Service with an AIDL interface that handles this internally. You can call real methods in such a service but you still would have to manage the service connection in `returnSomeValue()` if you don't want the user to do that.

Comment: I need the first approach.

Problem with AIDL is that I would have to rewrite basically everything and that I would have to implement the synchronization that comes naturally using Messengers myself.

Do you have any idea how to wait for the Handler? As the handler is synchronized I just can't seem to find any approach how a function can wait for it. (While the function is waiting the handler doesn't return.) Can I put the handler in a different thread somehow? I came across the HandlerThread but couldn't figure out if it helps me...

Comment: see code in updated answer - not sure if it really works for you but something like that could be a solution.

Comment: I ended up not using your code for I changed to AIDL after all.